# OutOfMemory Error while reading files to byte[]

Tags: java, android, file, out-of-memory, arrays

I am trying to read video files in a byte[] and then encrypt them. The files which are relatively large i.e. more than 30 mb are giving out of memory exception. Here is the code I am using to read the file to byte[]:

```
FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] fileContent = new byte[(int)file.length()];
fin.read(fileContent);
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
05-17 05:54:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4082): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 05:54:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4082): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-17 05:54:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at com.vencrypto.ExplorerActivity$3.onItemClick(ExplorerActivity.java:136)
05-17 05:54:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
05-17 05:54:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
05-17 05:54:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
05-17 05:54:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
05-17 05:54:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
05-17 05:54:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-17 05:54:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-17 05:54:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-17 05:54:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 05:54:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-17 05:54:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-17 05:54:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-17 05:54:59.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I know the files are too large but there must be a way right.

Comment: Instead of trying to allocate an array the size of the file, allocate an array of a manageable size, e.g. 2MB and use a loop that processes the file one chunk at a time, writing the chunks to a file output stream as you go along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `FileInputStream` directly, wrap that in a `BufferedInputStream`, so that you don't allocate huge amounts of memory. A buffered input stream reads the data in segments, so you can encrypt that piece, and, if you are writing it back to a file, use a `BufferedWriter` to write that file in the same way.

Comment: The important part is to not try to fit it all into a `byte[]` at once.  Work on smaller portions of the file at a time, or do all of your operations using the input/output streams themselves.

Comment: can you please elaborate the method a little. I guess I need to create the byte array for that too, the error is on the line where I am creating the byte[].

Comment: @Sourabh No, you don't need to create a byte array. Create a `BufferedInputStream` by using a `new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream())` (with the parameters that you've used). Have a look a the BufferedInputStream [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html). Inside the `BufferedInputStream`, it reads the data in small segments, which is how you should process your data, instead of one huge `byte[]`.